# Pardot Server Side Form Handler: Extract the cookie ID from the browser and pass it to the visitor_id

Tags: php, wordpress, pardot

I'm currently working on a system to post existing forms to a Pardot Form Handler via a server side process. I've got the form posting to Pardot via WordPress' helper function [wp_remote_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post) using the following code. (Its a CURL post at its core):

```
$response = wp_remote_post( 'https://ourdomain.com/l/82632/2018-04-26/544m2kc' , array(
        'timeout'   => 45,
        'body'      =>  $form_data
     )
);
```

However Pardot Requires a tracking cookie to be sent with the data. On site http://nebulaconsulting.co.uk/using-pardot-form-handlers/ there is the following quote:

> A server-side post can also pass the Pardot browser cookie through
>   with the data so future web activity can be tracked. This requires an
>   extra script to extract the cookie ID from the browser and pass it to
>   the visitor_id field in Pardot.

Does anyone have any help on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Zachary's answer is great but I'd like to point out that the visitor_id key doesn't match up exactly with the piAId (Account Id): it's the Account ID minus 1000.

Not sure why Pardot do this but I've confirmed it with multiple instances.

So if your piAid is 315092, your visitor_id key will be: **visitor_id314092**

Therefore, in Zachary's example, it will be: **'visitor_id' => 'Value of visitor_id314092 cookie'**

Comment: I can confirm that this is true, at least in my circumstance too.

Comment: The numeric part of the visitor_id key is your Pardot Account ID.  It's shown under Settings > Account > Pardot Account ID.

Comment: But how do you access the value of this cookie since it is a third-party cookie ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the visitor has viewed a page on your website with a Pardot tracking code in place before the form submission.  This sets a cookie with the visitor id, and you can retrieve its value (via JS) and include it in your server-side post to correlate it with that visitor.

1. In the Pardot tracking code, which relates to a specific campaign (and is found in its settings), you'll see: piAId = '315092';
2. The tracking script sets a cookie named: visitor_id315092 (i.e. visitor_id followed by the piAId value from above)
3. Retrieve this cookie's value and include it in the form post using the "visitor_id" key (NOT visitor_id315092)

'visitor_id' => 'Value of visitor_id315092 cookie'

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden iframe on a thank-you page that creates a client-side submission to the form handler. Essentially, an iframe is loaded on the page as a hidden pixel. The src of the iframe is your form handler’s endpoint URL loaded with all your field data as query parameters, email at the minimum required.